# tornado how to use WebSockets with wsgi

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, wsgi

I am trying to make a game server with python, using tornado.

The problem is that WebSockets don't seem to work with wsgi.

```
wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter(app)
server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server('', 5000, wsgi_app)
server.serve_forever()
```

After looking trough this answer on stackoverflow, [Running Tornado in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378847/running-tornado-in-apache), I've updated my code to use a `HTTPServer`, which works with websockets.

```
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
server.listen(5000)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

However when I use the HTTPServer, an error comes up saying: `TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Looking this up on the internet, I found an answer to the question here:
[tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication issue: __call__ takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484732/tornado-wsgi-wsgiapplication-issue-call-takes-exactly-3-arguments-2-given)

But after adding `tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer` around `app`, the error persists.

How can I solve this problem? Or is there any way to use tornado web sockets with wsgi.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.wsgi
import tornado.template
import tornado.httpserver
#import wsgiref.simple_server
import wsgiref

print "setting up environment..."

class TornadoApp(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):

        handlers = [

            (r"/chat", ChatPageHandler),
            (r"/wschat", ChatWSHandler),
            (r"/*", MainHandler)

        ]

        settings = {

            "debug" : True,
            "template_path" : "templates",
            "static_path" : "static"

        }

        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("test.html", food = "pizza")

class ChatPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("chat.html")

class ChatWSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    connections = []

    def open(self, *args):
        print 'a'
        self.connections.append(self)
        print 'b'
        self.write_message(u"@server: WebSocket opened!")
        print 'c'

    def on_message(self, message):
        [con.write_message(u""+message) for con in self.connections]

    def on_close(self):
        self.connections.remove(self)

print "done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TornadoApp()
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(app))
    server.listen(5000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Thank's in advace! Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPServer` needs a `tornado.web.Application`, which is not the same as a WSGI application (which you could use with `WSGIContainer`).

It is recommended that if you need both WSGI and websockets that you run them in two separate processes with an IPC mechanism of your choice between them (and use a real WSGI server instead of Tornado's `WSGIContainer`). If you need to do them in the same process, you can use a [`FallbackHandler`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.FallbackHandler).

```
wsgi_container = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(my_wsgi_app)
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/ws", MyWebSocketHandler),
    (r".*", FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_container),
])
```

Comment: What is `my_wsgi_app`?

Comment: That's the app you're building, the result of whatever WSGI framework you're using. The app you've pasted above is pure Tornado; there's no need to get anything WSGI-related involved if that's what your app looks like. You only need WSGI if you're using a WSGI-based framework like Flask.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you. I'll try that soon.